# Version of the C++ compiler on a Linux distro

Tags: linux

On a Linux distribution, is there a way to find out the version of the c++ compiler.
I tried running the following commands:

```
./opt/intel/bin/iccvars.sh intel64

icc -v
```

but on issuing the first command it returned no such file or directory.

Comment: which compiler do you have installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the gcc:

```
gcc --version
```

the above command should work.

If using g++ (for C++11 standard):

```
g++ --version
```

You can take a look at this for more information: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11